# How to detect if a video is in 360 format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, mp4, mediametadataretriever, 360-video

I have an interface where the user can upload a video that could be in 360 format (usually recorded with a special camera) or it could be a normal format, each case needs to be treated differently. So I need to detect the format of the uploaded video before treating it. Is there any JS library that can help in extracting some metadata from an mp4 file in order to detect if the video is in 360 format or not?

Any other suggestions to do this detection?

Thanks

Comment: **(1)** Different systems write their 360 data in different places. You'll have to use a **hex editor** to check what special bytes (metadata) those 360 videos have, then look for same values in `File`'s (buffer) Array using Javascript. Use `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` to get an Array. Use a While loop to search for byte sequences (find first byte value then use IF to check rest of required bytes, _eg:_ finding 4 required bytes). **(2)** Maybe look for a keyword like `spherical` in the metadata section of your video's bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @VC.One, your first proposition requires knowing how the video was recorded or which system wrote the 360 data, unfortunately, this is not possible in my case as the user is free to upload any video he wants. My check will be needed for testing the user input at the first level and then for treating the video. However, your second proposition may help, although I am searching for a standard way to do it and your way is like a hack :) but it should help ! Do you know how to access the metadata section in a video using javascript ?

Comment: **(1)** _"...Your first proposition requires knowing how..."_ Yes it does and that's why nobody asks a question like what is in your Title. Either your app knowingly supports the metadata style of GoPro or Google or Xiaomi or CAMM or whatever... Or  else the user can tick some box if their video is 360 to let your app know in advance

Comment: **(2)** You find the MP4 metadata in the MOOV section of an MP4 (that means byte sequence `6D 6F 6F 76` to spell ASCII letters `m o o v`) so you search for `if ( myArray[i] == 0x6D ) //# if "m" is found`. You can also use `&` to stitch sequences.  `if ( ( myArray[i] == 0x6D ) && ( myArray[i+1] == 0x6F ) )` etc... the size of MOOV is the previous 4 bytes before the word "moov" (check how to create Integer from 4 byte values in any coding language, it's same rules).

Comment: **(2)** continued... Summary: Find the word "moov", check its size from reading the prev 4 bytes, read forwards up to **size** amount, where you are looking for `73 70 68 65 72 69 63 61 6C` to spell "spherical" if such value exists in the metadata. A quick trick is to just create a sub-array (from start of MOOV up to SIZE length) and then read the array as if it was text (the byte values that are ASCII will become text) so you can use String functions to find text "spherical" (_eg:_ using `indexOf`).

Comment: @VC.One thanks for your explanation about (2), it is more clear like this, I will try it. Just one remark concerning (1), this detection will be necessary for the testing the user input in any case and then will be needed to do the intended business treatment because you cannot be sure of what the user will upload in spite of all the instructions you give to him! ... I thought it might exist a standard way to write the 360 metadata.